# Prevent error 403 on invalid URL parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, url, http-status-code-403

I've links to my website which are clicked by users and not directly in my control to be changed or encoded properly.

URL looks like this

`http://mywebsite.com?email=%%username@company.com`

I want this URL not to be forbidden and prevent the error `403`

On other questions, people have said this "It is **mod_security's 10_asl_rules.conf** causing this error." I searched it and could not find *mod_security* on the PHP info page

here is how my .htaccess file looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)=[%25][%25](.+)
    RewriteRule (.*) $1/?%1=%2 [R=301,L,NC]

    ErrorDocument 403 "We are working on it..."

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you know how those URLs should look or just tryng to remove the complete query string (Everything after `?`) will do?

Comment: I like to remove %%

Comment: Or at least open the page and will clean the value using JavaScript

Comment: OK. You have to check the QUERY_STRING (`%{QUERY_STRING}`) for those characters in .htaccess or Apache configuration file and generate a new QUERY_STRING in the target URL without those characters.